# how I could build a sequence of reduction lazy and eager

Tags: haskell

Does anyone know how I sort sequence as a lazy list as well as a eager list, `sort [3,4,2,1]`, with this definition of `sort`

```
sort = foldr insert []
  where 
    insert x [] = [x]
    insert x (y:ys) =
        if x<y
            then x:y:ys
            else y:insert x ys
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a sequence of reduction lazy and eager"?  And what is the `?` symbol mean in `x?y`?

Comment: @bheklilr I guess he wants `sort` sequence as a lazy list as well as  a eager list. But that's my guess.

Comment: Your guess is right. This is what I want. Have you any idea of how could i do this?

Comment: maybe you can tell us what you tried so far and where the problem is (because this seems to be a homework problem)

Comment: I'm a beginner in haskell. I recently started studying programming. At first, I was just curios, but now i like it. I found this in a book: where d=sqrt(square b-4<a<c) e=2<a , and i thought this example can help me to solve this exercise, but I found that I didn't know how to resolve it. I understand your fear of not solve my "homework", but that was just my curiosity, at school I haven't yet reached this chapter.

Answer (score 2):

You have written an implementation of [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), which, like all other deterministic comparison-based sorting algorithms, is [strict](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_vs._non-strict). The first value returned by `sort` is defined to be the minimum of the input list, which means that `sort` has to inspect every element of the list to be sure it's found the minimum. You can't return a minimum value early because the *actual* minimum value might be right at the end of the list - you'll never know until you test them all.

So `sort` can't possibly be lazy. If the list is infinite, it'll never return a value. If any elements of the list are `undefined`, it'll crash.

In other words, your version of `sort` (and, as I say, *any* deterministic comparison-based `sort`) treats lazy lists *just the same* as eager lists (those that have been fully evaluated to [normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_form_(abstract_rewriting))) - it will always evaluate every element of the input before it produces any output.

Answer (score 0):

[Selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) can be implemented both <strike>non-strictly</strike> incrementally and strictly.

#### Incremental selection sort

```hs
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort []     = []
sort (x:xs) = let (y, ys) = foldr select (x, []) xs
              in y : sort ys

select :: Ord a => a -> (a, [a]) -> (a, [a])
select x (y, ys)
    | x < y     = (x, y:ys)
    | otherwise = (y, x:ys)
```

#### Strict selection sort

```hs
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort []     = []
sort (x:xs) = let (y, ys) = foldr select (x, []) xs
              in let zs = sort ys in seq zs (y:zs)

select :: Ord a => a -> (a, [a]) -> (a, [a])
select x (y, ys)
    | x < y     = (x, y:ys)
    | otherwise = (y, x:ys)
```

However, selection sort always takes `O(n^2)` time for all cases. For most cases, it would be better to use the [`sort`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:sort) function exported by the `Data.List` module.

Comment: Non-strict in what sense?

Comment: @dfeuer You can get the smallest element of the list without having to sort the rest of the list. Should I call it lazy instead?

Comment: I believe that's generally called "incremental". Heap sorts using heaps with O(1) insertion are inherently incremental, but there are also incremental merge sorts (I think a bottom-up mergesort in Haskell is likely to be incremental, but I could be confused) and quick sorts (essentially hybrids between selection and sorting).

Comment: @dfeuer is right; this version is still strict. The `foldr` has to consume the whole list in order to determine the value of `y`. It may avoid _sorting_ the tail of the list before it returns a value, but it does not avoid _evaluating_ it.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Of course it has to evaluate the entire list in order to find the smallest element of the list. That's exactly why I mentioned that selection sort always takes `O(n^2)` time for all cases. If you see the algorithm of selection sort then it is a loop nested within a loop. The outer loop can be made non-strict. However, the inner loop has to be strict. When I said that selection sort is non-strict I meant that the outer loop is non-strict. It only produces the next smallest element on demand and I believe that's what the OP was looking for. So technically my answer is not wrong.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Anyway, I understood your argument. If there's any `undefined` values in the list then the sorting algorithm will halt. Hence, there's no non-strict algorithm for sorting. I edited my answer and corrected my terminology. Mind removing the downvote?

Comment: Thanks all of you for all the explanations. They helped me a lot to understand this problem.